# How to vertically center rotated text in a div with a float attribute?

Tags: html, css

I tried to display vertical text exactly in center of div (navigation button) which is nested in floating element, I set size,magin:auto, vertical-align but text is on the edge against center.
Is there any other way to put the text where it should be **without using absolute positioning**?

```
<nav>
      <div class="button"><p class="rotare">1st button</p></div>
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">1</div>
      <div class="button">1</div>
</nav>

nav {
    width: 50px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 0px;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.rotare {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        background-color: white;
        margin:auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can u add JSFiddle demo?

Comment: Why so strict against absolute positioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with absolute positioning, but without having to manually push the content into its place by simply adding these rules to your existing css:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
}

.rotare {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/grammar/NgrWg/
And here's an article explaining this method of vertical centering in more detail: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

**EDIT - secondary approach without absolute positioning**

Another approach is to use `table` and `table-cell` as the display property for the wrapper and text respectively. I've updated the fiddle to show that method as well: http://jsfiddle.net/grammar/NgrWg/1/.

Here's another article that explains this `table-cell` trick, and also outlines a third technique for centering things vertically: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't work :(. Text is now still on the edge of nav but in the middle height.

Comment: Try the second method I added. Maybe that is more what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it is! Text is in the buttons centre :), but if you change .rotare background-color to other than white, you can see that cells are horizontal- with button it look like big +.

Comment: Well now we're getting into fixing problems with the other css... let me see what I can do.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you :) I've made only one change: set margin to 0px in .button-want them to stick each other.